# Is blob storage account "Redundancy" important when I use CDN?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, cdn, redundancy

I am using Azure CDN with blob storage account as endpoint. My data is static and changes only once per year. I am not sure: **does it has some impact when I choose blob storage account "Redundancy" as "LRS" vs "GRS"?**

I hope that CDN will cache my data in different regions and that blob storage is needed only for first time when CDN gets data from blob storage.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the CDN perspective, I don't think the redundancy matters because CDN will cache the content and the content will be served from CDN nodes. Redundancy becomes important from data protection perspective.

If you go with LRS and assuming that the datacenter becomes completely inoperable, then you will lose all the source content.

If you opt for GRS, at least you have a copy of your content (though it will not be directly accessible to you) and in case datacenter becomes completely inoperable, your data is not lost and Microsoft will switch to the secondary location.

Recommendation would be to go with GRS over LRS. If you want access to the content in secondary region, then you should go with RA-GRS.